# MySQL - Insert foreign key if not exist

Tags: mysql, database, select, foreign-keys, sql-insert

First i have a table users:

| id | name | lastname | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | mr44 |

Then i have a table comments, `user_id` is a `FOREIGN KEY` of users table

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

I am inserting the `user_id` with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO comments(user_id)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = "mr44"));
```

What i want to do now is insert the user_id only if it doesn't exist.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO comments(user_id)
VALUES (
(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = "mr44")

    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments  
    WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 1)
);
```

Comment: Forget about INSERT .. VALUES and study INSERT .. SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to found an answer that works

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO comments (user_id)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id from users WHERE username = "mr44") AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT user_id FROM comments WHERE user_id = 19
) LIMIT 1;
```